# Oracle APEX Cards not displaying all data

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an Oracle APEX application (current release) that is using CARDS. I WANT an icon with 4 text columns to be displayed.  I am getting an icon with 3 text columns displayed, and I don't know what I am doing wrong. The column card_subtitle is the column not showing.  The SQL I am using returns data for all attributes…

```
select
  path_id,
  name card_title,
  description card_subtitle,
  owner  card_text,
  'Benchmark data'      card_subtext,
  path_id card_initials,
…
```

When I run the query from SQL, card_subtitle does have data.  It is defined as varchar2 like the other columns. I have set template options to show 4 lines.  As an alternative, I have tried taking two columns and concatenating them together with an HTML break ('< b r >') in between, but < b r > is displayed, instead of causing a line break. (Note I had to put in extra spaces so that SO would actually show the code...)

When run, the card displays as:
[image]

My template options are defined as:
[image]

Comment: The template options mentions '3 columns', is that a possible problem? Additionally, to fix the '<br/>' not working, make sure that the content does not escape special characters (please note that this exposes the content to [script injection vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)).

Comment: Thomas - The 3 columns in the Template options refers to 3 columns of cards.  If I change it to 4, my page now displayed 4 columns of cards going across the page.  So that did not help.  I did verify that the Attribute 'Strip HTML' is set to No. It was (unfortunately)....

Comment: Then it is hard for me to say what could be wrong without seeing the developer screen of the APEX page itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select the column and in the security tab under "Escape special characters" choose the option NO.

this is for the line break to work

Comment: Not a perfect solution, since it is a work-around, but it works...  good enough for me!

Comment: @user1009073 Cards type in Oracle Apex doesn't have a column therefore security-escape special characters. I have the same issue, the only way I could fix it was         
var html = $(this).text();
$(this).html(html);       
Using this js snippet but I needed timeout for this to work. Then another issue popped out: how many ms should I use for the timeout. Because when the card number increases, timeout starts to be insufficient. Are there any other ideas or solution to that?

Comment: You can use advanced formatting and use &MYCOLUMN!RAW.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

```
 1.Select the region 
 2.select the region attribute 
 3.goto the card region template 
 4.select the body text auto it will show the full content
```

[image]

there is only one disadvantage, that means, if you are enabled body text auto, the card alignment issue will came.